# WF 4 persist and durable workflow

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

i want to ask if i can make persist and durable workflow application without using workflow services. is that possible ?. Because as i found in a forum the only way to persist workflows is with workflow services. Thx for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can also persist workflows hosted in a `WorkflowApplication`.  You just can't use persistence with `WorkflowInvoker`.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/11/19/windows-workflow-foundation-4-and-persistence.aspx) shows how to persist your workflow using a **WorkflowApplication** as well as a WorkflowServiceHost.